# Trying to hide empty rows while ignoring the first column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table I am trying to make a little less huge. It had days of the week across the top and time slots in column 1. I am trying to hide rows whose content is empty, but I need to ignore the column one time slots (td class="rt-cell-1" in my example below).

Is there a way to do this using CSS?

Here is a snippet:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>TIME</th>

      <th>MONDAY</th>

      <th>TUESDAY</th>

      <th>WEDNESDAY</th>

      <th>THURSDAY</th>

      <th>FRIDAY</th>

      <th>SATURDAY</th>

      <th>SUNDAY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rt-cell-1">8:00 AM</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-2">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-3"><a href="#" target="_blank">Study Hall (Zoom)</a></td>

      <td class="rt-cell-4">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-5">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-6">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-7">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-8">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="rt-cell-1">8:30 AM</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-2">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-3">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-4">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-5">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-6">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-7">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-8">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="rt-cell-1">9:00 AM</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-2">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-3">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-4">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-5">Theatre Club (Vimeo)</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-6">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-7">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="rt-cell-8">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? jQuery can iterate all rows and check for empty cells excluding 1st cell with `not(td:first-child)` selector

Comment: Not with your current layout. `&nbsp` != empty. Also there is no CSS parent selector so even if you could detect empty cells except for the first column, you would not be able to hide the row.

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM you can do that like this ?

(rows are indexed from 0 = header in your case, columns / cells too)

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0].rows;
for(var y=1;y<rows.length;y++) {
  var row = rows[y].cells;
  var empty = true;
  for(var x=1;x<row.length;x++) {
    if (row[x].innerText.trim().length > 0) {
      empty = false;
      break;
    }
  };
  if (empty) {
    console.log('Row',y,'empty except time',row[0].innerText)
    rows[y].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>TIME</th><th>MONDAY</th><th>TUESDAY</th><th>WEDNESDAY</th><th>THURSDAY</th><th>FRIDAY</th><th>SATURDAY</th><th>SUNDAY</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td class="rt-cell-1">8:00 AM</td>
    <td class="rt-cell-2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="rt-cell-3"><a href="#" target="_blank">Study Hall (Zoom)</a></td><td class="rt-cell-4">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-5">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-6">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-7">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-8">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rt-cell-1">8:30 AM</td>
    <td class="rt-cell-2">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-3">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-4">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-5">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-6">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-7">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-8">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rt-cell-1">9:00 AM</td>
    <td class="rt-cell-2">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-3">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="rt-cell-5">Theatre Club (Vimeo)</td><td class="rt-cell-6">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-7">&nbsp;</td><td class="rt-cell-8">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not using CSS, but very simple ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to not display a empty row with the pseudo-class :empty

```css
tbody tr:empty{ display:none; }
```

It is possible to display the time in a pseudo-element based on a data-hour attribute of the TR :

```html
<tr data-hour="8:00"><td>Study Hall (Zoom)</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

```css
tbody tr::before{ content: attr(data-hour); color: red;}
```

But it seems that it is not possible to combine both of them with a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element.

```css
tbody tr:empty{ display:none; }
tbody tr:not(:empty)::before{ content: attr(data-hour); color: red;}
```

Tested on Firefox and Chromium.